# router navigation doesnt work after a number of clicks

Tags: durandal

I have a bug in navigation panel.

```
    <div class="wrapper" id="mainWrapper" data-bind="router: {
transition: 'fader',
duration: 300,
fadeOnly: true,
cacheViews: router.activeItem.cacheViewDuringComposition,
alwaysAttachView: router.activeItem.alwaysAttachView }">
```

I quickly clicked several times on navigation panel and navigation freezes.
property isProcessing always == true in router

```
 function dequeueInstruction() 
 {
             if (isProcessing()) {
                 return;
             } ...
```

Comment: Are all of your activate methods returning a promise?  Does it happen on one view or all of them?

Comment: looks a lot like this issue: https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/276

Answer (score 0):

this is issue with durandal.
set the cacheView to true then it will not freez.
hope it will work.